# Flutter || Alternative package for google maps

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, fluttermap

i want to use map but not `google maps` to get my location coordinate and take the data to use it for some purpose, is there any package that are same as google maps ?
for some reason i cannot use google maps bcs it's not my self project

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map if you want to show a map. But if you only need to know the device coordinate, I recommend using this library https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator